# Explicitly set the storage path of an image clicked using Cordova API

Tags: android, image, cordova, path, location

I am extremely new to Cordova and am working on the Android platform. I need to store an image in a custom location. 
The `navigator.camera.getPicture` method stores the clicked image in the cache, but I need to store that image in a custom folder in the root. How can I accomplish this? Any suggestions in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Camera plugin store data in Android/Data/my.package.com/ directory.This directory is always accessible from your app even if you didn't grant read/write permission in manifest file of Android.It is always safe to do this while developing a API.
If you still you want to change and store file at custom location then create your own plugin to achieve this.